# Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1954115647 "(null)"

Tags: ios, swift

So I have an AVAudioPlayer, sometimes it works great, but sometimes it prints the error "Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1954115647 "(null)"". Here is the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    downloadFileFromURL(url: URL(string: mainPreviewURL)!)
}

func downloadFileFromURL(url: URL) {
    var downloadTask = URLSessionDownloadTask()
    downloadTask = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
        customURL, response, error in

        self.play(url: customURL!)
    })
    downloadTask.resume()
}

func play(url: URL) {
    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        player!.prepareToPlay()
        player!.play()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you allowing arbitrary loads in your info.plist? Let me know if you dont know what that is and ill post it as an answer.

Comment: No, but all requests are from HTTPS.

Comment: This error isn't happening everytime, just sometimes

Comment: Let me know if my solution worked for you.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please let me know if it fixed your issue.

Comment: Still get the error.

Comment: Maybe it is something wrong with `downloadFileFromURL(url: )` ?

Comment: Where is the error happening? Can you edit your post to show.

Comment: It's printed by the "catch" in the play(url: ) function.

Comment: @Timmy, do you have other ideas?

Comment: Can you try calling the play function directly instead of calling downloadFileFromUrl?

Comment: Doing so gives me that error always.

Comment: Are you playing mp3's?

Comment: Yes, I am playing just mp3.

Comment: I updated my answer and changed the fileTypeHint, let me know how it it goes.

Comment: It behaves like before, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @Dimitrie-TomaFurdui Take a look to my answer if you haven't yet solved your issue..

Comment: I have recently found out that this will often go away after a reboot! So it's likely some Apple error. In other words; I got the error on a song file when trying two different methods shown here, then on reboot both methods worked! I'm on Ventura.

Answer (score 5):

Make the code in your do statement look like this:

```
    let songData = try NSData(contentsOfURL: songURL!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(data: songData!, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMpegLayer3)
    player!.prepareToPlay()
    player!.play()
```

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe'

Comment: Sorry about that, not at my computer so I couldn't see if that was an old one or not. Updated and should work.

Comment: let data = try! Data(contentsOf: fileURL!)
            player = try! AVAudioPlayer(data: data, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)
            player.prepareToPlay()

This worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

When you have this kind of error code usually your audio files are not recognized by Xcode / OS or corrupted. To verify this step, you can select one of your audio file and try to playing it inside Xcode:

[image]

If you have , instead of this picture, the total absence of your media player like this image:

[image]

probably you should fix your audio files. I checked it and I've seen that sometimes it happened when you use versioning operation system like **GIT** (git merging, pulling from other systems..) or when you made copies of your files to another system. **BUT** you should remember that High Sierra can play FLAC's audio from the FINDER preview instead of Sierra, so your issue could be related simply to your current OS.

Solution: remove and restore the original audio file/files version. If you try to use it in a simulator running to Sierra you could continue to have this issue, make your tries to High Sierra and see what happened.

Comment: The problem is that the files are downloaded from the server, and the same file sometimes works, sometimes doesn’t

Comment: Where do you try this app? Have you ever launched it to simulator or we speak about a real device?

Comment: It’s on a real device.

Comment: Take a look to the audio files attributes: usually you should have 44100 Hz 16 bit to be sure to have a full compatibility

Comment: I try to help you: are you sure do you launch play always in main thread after your network calls? I mean: `DispatchQueue.main.async { play... }`c

Comment: Have you try to launch your play after 0.25 seconds? Syntax: `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
    // your code here
}`

Comment: It’s the same thing

Answer (score 0):

For me, my app had entitlements "NSFileProtectionComplete" in my app. This caused audio to stop playing

With this setting, if your app imports audio files (instead of being bundled with the app), then you need to write files so that they have permission to play in the background, otherwise the files by default will all have "completeFileProtection" and AVAudioPlayer won't be able to decode your files shortly after going into the background.

```
try data.write(to: fileURL, options: .completeFileProtectionUnlessOpen)
```

From:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/encrypting_your_app_s_files